# Phalcon 2.x skeleton app with modules doesn't produce 404 Not Found if path is not found

Tags: php, nginx, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I've generated a skeleton app using dev tools that has a single module.
The problem I have is that whatever URL I type in the browser - it always returns the content in `apps/frontend/views/index.volt` (frontend is the module name).

Here is my services.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Services are globally registered in this file
 *
 * @var \Phalcon\Config $config
 */

use Phalcon\Mvc\Router;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlResolver;
use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Files as SessionAdapter;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as DbAdapter;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Metadata\Memory as MetaDataAdapter;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Volt as VoltEngine;

/**
 * The FactoryDefault Dependency Injector automatically registers the right services to provide a full stack framework
 */
$di = new FactoryDefault();

/**
 * Registering a router
 */
$di->set('router', function () {
    $router = new Router();

    $router->setDefaultModule('frontend');
    $router->setDefaultNamespace('Homediary\Frontend\Controllers');

    return $router;
});

/**
 * The URL component is used to generate all kinds of URLs in the application
 */
$di->set('url', function () {
    $url = new UrlResolver();
    $url->setBaseUri('/Homediary/');

    return $url;
});

/**
 * Setting up the view component
 */
$di->setShared('view', function () use ($config) {

    $view = new View();

    $view->setViewsDir($config->application->viewsDir);

    $view->registerEngines(array(
        '.volt' => function ($view, $di) use ($config) {

            $volt = new VoltEngine($view, $di);

            $volt->setOptions(array(
                'compiledPath' => $config->application->cacheDir,
                'compiledSeparator' => '_',
                'stat' => true,
                'compileAlways' => true
            ));

            return $volt;
        },
        '.phtml' => 'Phalcon\Mvc\View\Engine\Php'
    ));

    return $view;
});

/**
 * Database connection is created based in the parameters defined in the configuration file
 */
$di->set('db', function () use ($config) {
    return new DbAdapter($config->database->toArray());
});

/**
 * If the configuration specify the use of metadata adapter use it or use memory otherwise
 */
$di->set('modelsMetadata', function () {
    return new MetaDataAdapter();
});

/**
 * Starts the session the first time some component requests the session service
 */
$di->setShared('session', function () {
    $session = new SessionAdapter();
    $session->start();

    return $session;
});

/**
* Set the default namespace for dispatcher
*/
$di->setShared('dispatcher', function() use ($di) {
    $dispatcher = new Phalcon\Mvc\Dispatcher();
    $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace('Homediary\Frontend\Controllers');
    return $dispatcher;
});
```

And routes.php

```
<?php

$router = $di->get("router");

foreach ($application->getModules() as $key => $module) {
    $namespace = str_replace('Module','Controllers', $module["className"]);
    $router->add('/'.$key.'/:params', array(
        'namespace' => $namespace,
        'module' => $key,
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'params' => 1
    ))->setName($key);
    $router->add('/'.$key.'/:controller/:params', array(
        'namespace' => $namespace,
        'module' => $key,
        'controller' => 1,
        'action' => 'index',
        'params' => 2
    ));
    $router->add('/'.$key.'/:controller/:action/:params', array(
        'namespace' => $namespace,
        'module' => $key,
        'controller' => 1,
        'action' => 2,
        'params' => 3
    ));
}

/*
//Set 404 paths
$router->notFound(array(
    "controller" => "index",
    "action"     => "notFoundAction"
));
*/
```

And nginx config

```
 server {
   listen                *:80;

   server_name           homediary.dev www.homediary.dev;
   client_max_body_size 100m;

   root /var/www/public;
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;

   access_log            /var/log/nginx/nxv_tygjjhwtk0si.access.log;
   error_log             /var/log/nginx/nxv_tygjjhwtk0si.error.log;

   location / {

     root  /var/www/public;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
     autoindex off;
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;


   }

   location ~ \.php$ {

     root  /var/www/public;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
     #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
     try_files $uri =404;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
     fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;

   }

   sendfile off;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in nginx config passing route in REQUEST_URI vs a special _url variable. To make Phalcon work with this setting I had to add

`$router->setUriSource(Router::URI_SOURCE_SERVER_REQUEST_URI);`

right after

`$router = new Router();`

then it started working as it should :)